# Local functions with anonymous types in their scope

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types, c#-7.0

I'm playing with VS 2017 RC and new C# features:

```
class Program
 {
        class A
       {
            public int Z1 { get; set; }
            public int Z2 { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var q = new[] { new A() }.Select(x => new { x.Z2 });
            Do(q.First());
            int Do<T>(T p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.GetType().Name);
                return 0;
            }
       }
}
```

The code above does compile and outputs

> ```
> "<>f__AnonymousType0`1"
> ```

However, the following does not:

```
Console.WriteLine(p.Z2);
```

producing

> Error CS1061  'T' does not contain a definition for 'Z2' and no
>   extension method 'Z2' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is this something not finished yet? Will we be able to access properties of anonymous types inside local functions after the release?

Comment: Can you add any reference source that makes you think it should work? Haven't seen that one yet.

Comment: This will behave identically to a non-local function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not related to local functions at all. This is a limitation (by design) of C# generics.

You can't access `.Z2` inside of the function because not every possible type will have it.

If you de-generalise your method and require an `A` instead, this will work.

```
        int Do(A p) {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Z2);
            return 0;
        }
```